# How come I can't implement Django's forget password feature?

Tags: python, django

```
Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'uidb36': '1', 'token': '2u6-e139d87034d52a80c572'}' not found.
```

I already did this correctly:

```
(r'^password/reset/?$',password_reset ),
(r'^password/reset/done/?$',password_reset_done ),
(r'^password/reset/confirm/?$',password_reset_confirm ),
(r'^password/reset/complete/?$',password_reset_complete),
```

Comment: Looks like your urls are imprperly configured. Are these urls included to your main project urls file? In which file does these url entries exist? Can you provide full content of it? Check the docs about urls: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

Comment: How is it improperly configured?

Answer (score 11):

Django is passing arguments itself; you need to accept them and pass them to the reset form.

To be really clear about what the error message is saying, it is expecting a url for the view, 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', and that url **MUST** accept the arguments provided, in this case 'uidb36' and 'token'. If it does not, it just keeps looking until it gets to the end of your urls and then throws this error.

Something like the following should work:

```
(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>\d+)/(?P<token>[\d\w-]+)$',password_reset_confirm ),
```

Personally, I'd kind of prefer if those were passed in a GET rather than the URL, but whatever :).

Comment: Your URL regex doesn't work. uidb36 is a base36 variable, result of django.utils.http.int_to_base36, but not a decimal.

Comment: Correct regex ends with: '/(?P<uidb36>[\d\w]+)/(?P<token>[\d\w-]+)$'. Answer edited ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing it arguments. None of those urlconf entries take arguments. Either drop them from the reverse or add them to the urlconf.

Comment: I'm not passing in any arguments? Where am I doing that?   I don't know what reverse is. I just followed the docs and inserted these 4 lines (plus the import)

Comment: @TIMEX: As always, see your traceback.

Comment: I dont get it, how am I passing arguments when I just have the view name on each line?   My traceback says that it flops on form.save(**opts) in my contrib.auth.views.py

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset  It says everything is optional.

Comment: @TIMEX: To the *function*, yes. But that doesn't mean that the urlconf entry can follow the same thing.

Comment: So I need to pass a template?

Comment: @TIMEX: You need to construct your urlconf to accept the arguments that may be passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have a templatetag of this kind in a template file

```
{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm %}
```

try to search for something like that
shell example:

```
find . -iname "*.html" -exec grep -iH "django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm" {} \;
```

If you find some then check that no arguments are "passed"